# Update Statement with date using php

Tags: php, oracle

```
function DBClosedTicket($TRANSACTIONID,$TRANSACTIONTYPE='')

{

    $CLOSEDATE = DBGetDate(); //ex. value is 2013:01:02 17:03:20

    $strQuery = "UPDATE TBL_TRANSACTION SET TRANSACTION_TYPE = :TRANSACTIONTYPE, CLOSE_DATE = :CLOSEDATE WHERE TRANSACTION_ID = :TRANSACTIONID";

    $stmt = oci_parse(DBConnect(), $strQuery);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':TRANSACTIONID', $TRANSACTIONID);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':TRANSACTIONTYPE', $TRANSACTIONTYPE);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':CLOSEDATE', $CLOSEDATE);

    oci_execute($stmt);
    return $strQuery;
}
```

no errors and no result how can i update with date in oracle using php

Comment: Why did you set `$TRANSACTIONTYPE` to null string at the function parameters?

Comment: $TRANSACTIONTYPE IS OPTIONAL MY PROBLEM IS DATE

Comment: oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':CLOSEDATE', $CLOSEDATE);

Comment: IF I REMOVE THE oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':CLOSEDATE', $CLOSEDATE); AND  REMOVE CLOSE_DATE = :CLOSEDATE IN UPDATE STATEMENT successfully execute the query

Comment: how can i update with date ex. format is 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'

Comment: did you check if the column name in the DB matche your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this statement so that Oracle understands the date format:

```
$strQuery = "UPDATE TBL_TRANSACTION SET TRANSACTION_TYPE = :TRANSACTIONTYPE, CLOSE_DATE = to_date(':CLOSEDATE', 'RRRR:MM:DD HH24:MI:SS') WHERE TRANSACTION_ID = :TRANSACTIONID";
```

I hope `DBGetDate()` returns a string value and data type of CLOSE_DATE is DATE in Oracle db.

If the above change do not work, try replacing single quotes from `':CLOSEDATE'`.